# Unity PHP Post doesn't send POST variable

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I use WWWForm, It's not working with ssl connection,

if I use `http://` connection on secure domain it doesn't send POST variable and if I use `https://` it given error

> unknown error

So it just working and send variable only non-secure domain

Unity3d version is 2017.3.0p1

I tried windows and mac version

Here is c# code:

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();


    form.AddField("a", "var1");
    form.AddField("b", "var2");
    string url = "http://www.example.com/ajax/test.php";

    WWW w = new WWW(url, form);
    yield return w;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.error)) {
        Debug.Log(w.error);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log(w.text);
   }
```

It returns only `test`.

Here is test.php :

```
<?
echo 'test '.$_POST["a"];
?>
```

Please assist on me, what should I do?

Comment: Try putting 'http://' at the beginning of your URL.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I tried, but its not working

Comment: What's the output if you print a var_dump of $_REQUEST?

Comment: Here is the `var_dump` output `array(0) {}` @Demigod

Comment: It's good practice to use only `<?php` instead of `<?`. Then, how do you debug it? Are you checking the `Debug.Log(w.text)` data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug in Unity version `2017.3.0`. If you post data to a url hosted in a server using SSL and set to `rewrite/re-direct all`, it returns `unknown error`.

I believe it will be fixed soon, but you could consider to switch to version `5.3.8` to surpass this issue until it's fixed.

Comment: yeah that's right! I have uninstalled 2017.3.0 and installed 5.3.8 it's worked! it's not completely solution but it solved my problem for now